# How do I fix the Typescript error Unable to compile TypeScript:

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, mongoose

I have not been able to figure out the reason for the error I am getting. I'm not a Typescript ninja so maybe the error is obvious to someone here. My project is running micro services using Kubernetes and one of the services is throwing the following error when I run the project.

I have Googled as much as seems possible and found nothing helpful. The error is very specific to some attempts to make mongoose play nicely.

Thanks in advance.

***My model file:***

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

import { Order, OrderStatus } from './order';

interface TicketAttrs {
  id: string;
  price: number;
  title: string;
}

export interface TicketDoc extends mongoose.Document {
  id: string;
  title: string;
  price: number;
  isReserved(): Promise<boolean>;
}

interface TicketModel extends mongoose.Model<TicketDoc> {
  build(attrs: TicketAttrs): TicketDoc;
}

const schema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  price: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
    min: 0
  }
}, {
  toJSON: {
    transform(doc, ret) {
      ret.id = ret._id;
      delete ret._id;
    }
  }
});

schema.statics.build = (attrs: TicketAttrs) => {
  return new Ticket({
    _id: attrs.id,
    price: attrs.price,
    title: attrs.title
  });
};

/**
 * Queries the orders to determine if a ticket is currently 
 * reserved.
 * 
 * @returns boolean
 */
schema.methods.isReserved = async function() {
  const existingOrder = await Order.findOne({
    ticket: this,
    status: {
      $in: [
        OrderStatus.Created,
        OrderStatus.AwaitingPayment,
        OrderStatus.Complete
      ]
    }
  });

  return !!existingOrder;
};

const Ticket = mongoose.model<TicketDoc, TicketModel>('Ticket', schema);

export { Ticket };
```

***The Error:***

[image]

[orders] Compilation error in /app/src/models/ticket.ts
[orders] [ERROR] 11:43:04 ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
[orders] src/models/ticket.ts(57,5): error TS2322: Type 'Document<any, {}>' is not assignable to type 'Pick<_LeanDocument, "id" | "_id" | "__v" | "title" | "price" | "isReserved"> | QuerySelector<Pick<_LeanDocument, "id" | ... 4 more ... | "isReserved">> | undefined'.
[orders]   Type 'Document<any, {}>' is missing the following properties from type 'Pick<_LeanDocument, "id" | "_id" | "__v" | "title" | "price" | "isReserved">': title, price, isReserved
[orders]

Comment: Please paste the error message as text rather than as a screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Schema is a generic constructor, so try this:
`new mongoose.Schema<TicketDoc>({...})`

I brought the idea from [here](https://medium.com/@agentwhs/complete-guide-for-typescript-for-mongoose-for-node-js-8cc0a7e470c1) out.

Comment: It says it can only accept one argument, so I tried the following and it worked. I don't know why though, do you? Might want to update your answer so as to not confuse others. This worked const schema = new mongoose.Schema<TicketDoc>